# Jersey client add Accept headers automatically

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

Using the Jersey Client API for our Automation framework and encountered a pretty annoying functionality where the client will add default `Accept` headers if non are set. On top of this the debug trace does not print out those extra headers and was not until actually using a network sniffer we would see the default headers.

Added default header:

```
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\r\n
```

I have been searching the documentation but with no luck. Is there a way prevent adding the default headers(We are executing specific test where the header should not exist)

Also would be great if the logs would include headers been added automatically, anyway to enable this?

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900870/how-do-i-get-jersey-test-client-to-not-fill-in-a-default-accept-header

Comment: Missed that one, thanks.. I will close this one