# Is '*' a valid wildcard for a content type according to HTTP spec?

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, http-accept-header

We're using the Jersey reference implementation of Jax-RS. The Jax-RS client implementation of Jersey is appending a default accept header to the request if no accept header is specified. The default accept header looks like this:

```
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

As you can see, it uses a single asterisk '*' as content-type (after image/jpeg).

In the Jax-RS spec (see [here](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/65cf4e5a319b24ae6c4b39a296980674b3307762/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.java#L72)), this single * is defined as

```
/**
 * The value of a type or subtype wildcard {@value #MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD}.
 */
public static final String MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD = "*";
```

which I interpret as "wildcard for any media type"

The '*/*' is defined as

```
/**
 * A {@code String} constant representing wildcard {@value #WILDCARD} media type .
 */
public final static String WILDCARD = "*/*";
```

which I interpret as "wildcard for any media range"

However, the HTTP spec ([RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)) does not mention an "any media type" wildcard, only media-range wildcards:

```
media-range    = ( "*/*"
                 / ( type "/" "*" )
                 / ( type "/" subtype )
                 ) *( OWS ";" OWS parameter )

(..)

The asterisk "*" character is used to group media types into ranges,
with "*/*" indicating all media types and "type/*" indicating all
subtypes of that type.  The media-range can include media type
parameters that are applicable to that range.
```

Which I interpret as allowed content-types:

- */*
- text/*
- text/plain

in other words, the content type has to be *always* of the form "something slash something" or "a single * is not a valid content type". Although, the latter is not explicitly stated.

Now both specs are publicly standardized, with the HTTP spec being somewhat the parent document to the Jax-RS spec as Jax-RS is based on HTTP. IMHO both standards contradict each other regarding the wildcard content types.

Question is, what is applicable?

- Is a single asterisk "*" a valid content type (allowing the server to respond with any content type")
- OR should the use of the single asterisk should produce an error? If yes, which one?

  - 400 Bad Requst
  - 406 not acceptable
- OR should the server be more tolerant and treat the * same as the wildcard */* although * is no valid content type (and probably produce a warning in the log or something)?

### Edit

While dealing with Jsoup (not JaxRS/Jersey), I observed, that JSoup is using the same default accept types and it seems, the default headers are an implementation detail of the `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`

```
static final String acceptString = "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2";
```

So in case this is a bug, it's not a bug in Jersey, but Java's HttpURLConnection

Comment: I think it is important to know which client are you referring to when you say "The Jax-RS client implementation of Jersey is appending a default accept header to the request". Can you please clarify?

Comment: I create & use a Jax-RS client using the Jersey reference implementation. When I don't specify an accept header, Jersey sets the default header (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900870/how-do-i-get-jersey-test-client-to-not-fill-in-a-default-accept-header)

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> which I interpret as "wildcard for any media type"

I think that is incorrect. It is a wildcard for type or subtype. The wildcard for any media type is defined as `*/*`, like in the HTTP spec.

Also, when in doubt, follow the HTTP spec. In the end, that is the communication protocol you are using. The other party might not know about the Jax-RS spec.

Comment: so you say, the jax-rs spec is incorrect (because it uses the * as wildcard for a content type)?

Comment: @GeraldMücke yes, it looks like that. On the other hand, following [Postel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), you might want to accept the `*` coming from a client and interpret it as `*/*`.

Comment: The intention in JAX-RS is different. It is a matching on the target side. This is just for matching the incoming request - which has a concrete media type like e.g. application/json - to a service endpoint.
If the ServiceEndpoint has e.g @Produces("*/json") then it will be used. An endpoint with @Produces("*/xml") obviously will not.
A ServiceEndpoing with @Produces("*) will match every requested Accept.

Comment: Problem is, the jersey client _sends_ the * wildcard content type in the request to the server, what if the server side is not a Jax-RS based rest service?

Comment: @GeraldMücke well, that will certainly depend on the server. I doubt it will create serious problems, but you will have to test thoroughly.

Comment: I agree that this is a Jersey problem.

Comment: @GeraldMücke added my answer with more details below.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the Jersey client library/code.

Looking through the JAX-RS specification at

> https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1542959568_b3be8ccd614accaf7749ade85e6ebf67

, I could not find any explicit mention of supporting a media type * . It explicitly mentions supported media types like "n/m" where m could be * or n and m could be *, but only * is nowhere mentioned.

A quote from the document:

> First, let us define the client media type and the server media type
>   as those denoted by the Accept header in a request and the @Produces
>   annotation on a resource method, respectively. Let a client media type
>   be of the form n/m;q=v1, a server media type be of the form n/m;qs=v2
>   and a combined media type of the form n/m;q=v1;qs=v2;d=v3, where the
>   distance factor d is defined below. For any of these types, m could be
>   ∗, or m and n could be ∗ and the values of q and qs are assumed to be
>   1.0 if absent

Thus, I believe there is something wrong with the Jersey client API which creates the default Accept header when there is no explicit one provided and sets its value to the one which you have mentioned, i.e.

```
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

Also, just to add here, the JAX-RS specification, mentions this:

```
(a) Filter M by removing members that do not meet the following criteria:
• The request method is supported. If no methods support the request method an implementation
MUST generate a NotAllowedException (405 status) and no entity. Note the
additional support for HEAD and OPTIONS described in Section 3.3.5.
• The media type of the request entity body (if any) is a supported input data format (see Section
3.5). If no methods support the media type of the request entity body an implementation
MUST generate a NotSupportedException (415 status) and no entity.
• At least one of the acceptable response entity body media types is a supported output data
format (see Section 3.5). If no methods support one of the acceptable response entity body
media types an implementation MUST generate a NotAcceptableException (406 status)
and no entity
```

Thus, 406 HTTP code would be appropriate if the requested media type (in Accept header) cannot be matched with any server supported methods' response media types.

However, in your case, there are various media types specified in the request including the generic one which supports all media types, so throwing an error wouldn't be the right thing to do, even though * is not exactly a correct media type.

Comment: Throwing an error is IMHO ok, as the request header field is malformed...

Comment: @JulianReschke that would make it restrictive and possibly become a blocker for the reporter, since he also pointed to another link which mentions developers had a hard time removing the default Accept header. Also, as indicated by Bart above, robustness is a good idea to be considered here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle

Comment: Understood. I just wanted to point out that it's OK according to the spec. Also keep in mind that drastic error handling helps keeping the protocol clean without nasty interop problems. See XML or HTTP/2.

Comment: Updated the URL link again, as it wasn't working earlier.

Comment: Corrected the response code from 415 to 406 in the description.